# Installing Eclipse Kepler

Tags: software-installation, eclipse

I need some help to set up the Eclipse Kepler 4.3 on Xubuntu, I whould like to do it by the command terminal. Which are the right commands?

Answer (score 34):

First of all, you need to check whether you have java installed on your system. You can check by using the command:

`java -version`

If java is not installed, then you should install it by doing

`sudo apt-get install default-jre`

Afterwards, download Eclipse from the download section of the official website (http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/). Remember to choose the correct package for your architecture (32bit or 64 bit). The package will have the name:

`eclipse-standard-kepler-SR1-linux-gtk-x86_32.tar.gz`

or

`eclipse-standard-kepler-SR1-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz`

After you have downloaded the correct package, extract the eclipse.XX.YY.tar.gz using

```
tar -zxvf eclipse.XX.YY.tar.gz
```

switch to root user:

```
sudo -i
```

Copy the extracted folder to /opt

```
cp -r eclipse.XX.YY /opt
```

Create a desktop file in the location /usr/share/applications and install it:

```
gedit eclipse.desktop
```

Copy the following to the eclipse.desktop file.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Eclipse 
Type=Application
Exec=eclipse
Terminal=false
Icon=eclipse
Comment=Integrated Development Environment
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Development;IDE;
Name[en]=Eclipse
```

Give the desktop file permission to be executed, run:

```
chmod +x eclipse.desktop
```

Run the following command to automatically install it in the unity:

```
desktop-file-install eclipse.desktop
```

Create a symlink in /usr/local/bin using

```
cd /usr/local/bin
ln -s /opt/eclipse/eclipse
```

For an eclipse icon to be displayed in dash, eclipse icon can be added as

```
cp /opt/eclipse/icon.xpm /usr/share/pixmaps/eclipse.xpm
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will do that... but is there any way to install everything from the command line?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to post the JDK install...    If you not fussed about running OpenJDK then its easy to install this with : -

`apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-7-jre`

Comment: If you MUST have oracle / Sun java then take a look at this: -
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java

Comment: You may want to edit your answer and add that.

Comment: If you had Eclipse Indigo installed from Software Center, should you remove that before installing Kepler from source? I followed these instructions with Indigo still in the system. And when I launched Eclipse, Kepler came up not Indigo. So I am not sure if it is still a good ideo to remove Indigo from software center.

Comment: Eclipse has a much better GUI self-installer now for linux - see instructions on their site here: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/?show_instructions=TRUE

Answer (score 3):

There' a bug that keeps the menu from working see
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-gtk-module/+bug/1208019

the work around is to change one line in the eclipse.desktop file

```
Exec=eclipse
```

to

```
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= eclipse
```

Also I had to make the desktop executable before I did the desktop-file-install in order to make it work.