# Eclipse Kepler on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation, eclipse

I am using Ubuntu 12.04LTS (32-bit). I am currently installing Eclipse Kepler using this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337281/installing-eclipse-kepler-and-java-jdk). I've finished the process but I can't get the `eclipse` display on the menu search. Currently, the `eclipse` icon is displayed along with its image, but the icon itself can't be clicked/entered. I have installed Oracle JDK 7 provided by this [tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7).

This I miss something that caused the icon/application to not run and/or cannot be clicked?

Comment: I may have missed/mistyped a line in tutorial(s). All is working now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Delete any previous launcher for Eclipse you may have made, this will create a completely new one.

Run these commands:

```
# Installs gnome-desktop-item-edit, a useful GUI to configure .desktop files
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends gnome-panel

# Symlinks eclipse to /usr/local/bin, allowing you to launch it from a command line
# If eclipse is not in /opt, change this to point to your eclipse executable
sudo ln -s /opt/eclipse*/eclipse /usr/local/bin/eclipse

# Creates a new .desktop file in '/usr/share/applications'
sudo gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new "/usr/share/applications/eclipse-ide.desktop"
```

Then, 
put these into the fields, leave others default (You can actually put whatever you want in these, except "Command"):

- Name: "Eclipse IDE"
- Command: Click the Browse button and find the `eclipse` executable file
- Icon: Click the springboard icon (towards the top left), then browse to the file `icon.xpm`, in the same folder as the `eclipse` executable

  - Note: The default Eclipse icon is very bad with Unity, you can't tell if it's launched or not. I personally use [this icon here](http://findicons.com/icon/download/93325/eclipse/128/png?id=94830). Just choose this downloaded icon instead of the default `icon.xpm`
- Comment: Anything you want, I put (from Wikipedia)

  > Eclipse is a multi-language IDE comprising a base workspace and an extensible plug-in system for customizing the environment.

Click "OK", then search the Dash for your new icon.

See this screenshot for reference only:
[image: Creating the eclipse launcher using above steps]

Answer (score 0):

Place the eclipse.desktop file in
  /home/your_user/.local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop

In addition, assure that the eclipse command is in your command path. it should be in /usr/local/bin according to your link. You can verify that you can run it by using the which command

```
which eclipse
```

If you cannot start eclipse from your home directory in your command line, try placing the full path name in the .desktop file

```
  :
Exec=/path/to/eclipse
  :
```

Comment: Is that correct `username/.share/eclipse.desktop'? So I am going to create a directory `.share`?

Comment: @Dr.Java This is wrong, it should be in `/home/your_user/.local/share/applications`, see [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/344988/176889) for a way to install it for all users of the computer

Comment: @minerz029 You are correct. I updated my post.