# Unistall Eclipse installed in /opt

Tags: java, eclipse, c++

I need Java Eclipse, but accidentally installed the C++ one using the steps from here [Installing Eclipse Kepler](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337281/installing-eclipse-kepler-and-java-jdk)

How do I actually remove the C++ one completely? I tried just removing the files from /opt ,removing the symbolic link and installing the Java over but the C++ still comes up when i call eclipse?

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I tried multiple methods none of which removed the eclipse installation in /opt. So finally I manually removed the folder

```
aniket@aniket-Compaq-610:~$ cd /opt
aniket@aniket-Compaq-610:/opt$ sudo rm -rf eclipse
```

Doing this will uninstall eclipse. But it will still appear in the unity search. To remove it from search as well delete eclipse.desktop file from /usr/share/applications

```
aniket@aniket-Compaq-610:~$ cd /usr/share/applications/
aniket@aniket-Compaq-610:/usr/share/applications$ sudo rm eclipse.desktop
```

If you want to remove your existing eclipse settings execute

```
rm -rf ~/.eclipse/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall Eclipse features in Eclipse. Open the `Help > About Eclipse` dialog and click the `Installation Details` button. This will show you all the components you have installed. Select the one you want to remove and click `Uninstall`.