# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS - No such file or directory

Tags: software-installation, eclipse

I'm trying to install:

- Eclipse EE Kepler (eclipse-jee-kepler-SR2-linux-gtk-x86_64)
- Oracle Express Edition (oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm)

whenever I try to access/install oracle setup using rpm *(I've installed rpm)* I encounter error, i.e.

> No such file or directory exists.

*And in case of Eclipse,*

If I try to extract eclipse file using tar command, still I get the same error of no such file or directory exists.

Comment: Why are you using RPM's to install eclipse? Did you check [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/337281/169736) out?

Answer (score 0):

Always try to use the package manager for your installations, so you support a long service life of your system as the packages within the package manager are trusted and verified.

The standard way to install packages is through the terminal. Within Ubuntu you have more "user friendly" applications like the Ubuntu software center.

Through the terminal you initiate every installation within Debian based distributions (like Ubuntu) with

`sudo apt-get install`

extended with the package name you want to install.

For example, if you want to install eclipse you use

`sudo apt-get install eclipse`

Before you install a program always favour the installation through the package management system. See https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/package-management.html for further information. I hope this was a help to get started.

Answer (score 0):

try installing synapic package manager then click update then apply then try what you was doing before see if that works