# Cannot install Eclipse Kepler (4.3)

Tags: java, software-installation, eclipse

I tried installing eclipse directly from the repo using apt-get, but it gave a outdated version -- Indigo 3.8, which does not support several important plug-ins.

So I started using Eclipse Kepler Without installation
I downloaded Eclipse (.tar.gz file) and extracted it and ran it using the
 `./eclipse`  command which was running successfully, but it does not support plug-ins when running the eclipse executable(eclipse x-ecutable) 
This is from the downloaded package of eclipse Kepler with bash.

Which didn’t work because I cannot get pyDev and Java EE plug-in, so I tried to install it by following the method here:

[Installing Eclipse Kepler](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337281/installing-eclipse-kepler)

This created a broken Desktop icon and I cannot find any installation in Dash

I am currently running Ubuntu 14.04.  Is there any way to manually install a plug-in to the eclipse package which I am running manually if there is no installation solution?

Comment: Try typing `eclipse` in a terminal (search for terminal) and tell me if it runs.

Comment: no it dosen't run I need installation I cannot install it at all and i also don't know how to install the plugins manually

Comment: How exactly you installed it and how are you trying to execute it?

Comment: If u need it badly, download it from eclipse.com and extract it and execute the app directly.

Comment: @Moga That is exactly what i have done and it is not working , I cannot download pulg-in which i want

Comment: @Braiam I didn't really installed it i just downloaded a tar ball and runned the app

Comment: Be more detailed about what you have done and what you are trying to do and any error your find. Also include the content of the file you are trying to use.

Comment: Try to execute the file from the terminal and post any errors or post screenshot.

Comment: no errors eclipse runs successfully all that it can't do is find plugin and install them and is very slow as it dosen't run like standard installed apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one way out to this problem and that is to download it manually and install the kepler version manually by following steps

1. go to the downloaded package directory and unpack package

   cd {directory where your browser downloaded the package to}
    tar -zxvf eclipse-SDK-3.4.1-linux-gtk.tar.gz && mv eclipse /opt
2. make scirpt

   nano /bin/eclipse

   now enter following to the scirpt

   export MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME="/usr/lib/mozilla/"

   export ECLIPSE_HOME="$HOME/opt/eclipse"

   `$ECLIPSE_HOME/eclipse $*
3. Execute the script

   chmod +x /bin/eclipse

This will add entry to the terminal so  you can access eclipse by typing 
eclipse directly on terminal, if you want to add any new plugin you have to do it manually for more info on manuall installation of plugin see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757391/how-to-manually-install-software-plugin-to-eclipse-ide)

for more info see this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EclipseIDE)