# Installing eclipse on Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, eclipse

I've followed the exact steps provided by: [Installing Eclipse Kepler](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337281/installing-eclipse-kepler) , I receive the eclipse icon in the start menu (or whatever u call it in Linux systems) however when I click in it, it remains idle and nothing happens, and it doesn't open up the IDE, also when I navigate towards the eclipse folder using the terminal and I type eclipse I receive the following message:

```
root@mossig-linux:/opt/eclipse# eclipse
-bash: /usr/local/bin/eclipse: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message `cannot execute binary file: Exec format error` shows you have download wrong architecture.

Here you may downloaded 64-bit version of Eclipse Kepler for 32-bit system(Ubuntu).

If you are running 32-bit system, [Download -> eclipse-standard-kepler-SR2-linux-gtk.tar.gz](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/kepler/SR2/eclipse-standard-kepler-SR2-linux-gtk.tar.gz)

Else If 64-bit system, [Download -> eclipse-standard-kepler-SR2-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/kepler/SR2/eclipse-standard-kepler-SR2-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz)

Comment: Thanks a lot, my system is x86, I tought I've downloaded the 32 bit version. I makes sure Ill download it correct this time. Thank you.

Comment: @MossigStamboulian If your problem solved, accept the answer.. it will help other may have same problem...

Comment: oops sorry, I'm new to this blog as well, by accept you mean to click on the tick button on the left side of you answer yeah?

Comment: @MossigStamboulian yes

Comment: @MossigStamboulian also you can upvote by clicking **^** near to accept..